# BizTalk 2010 w/ Clustered SQL MSDTC Requirement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, biztalk, biztalk-2010, cluster-computing

I'm installing BizTalk 2010 in a clustered environment. There will be a BizTalk cluster in addition to a separate SQL Server cluster.

According to my research, with SQL Server 2008 clustering the MSDTC is no longer a requirement for installing the SQL instance.

Is it required for BizTalk 2010 to cluster the MSDTC on the SQL Servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping MSDTC running [is critical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634522%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx) to having a highly-available BizTalk environment. Clustering MSDTC may not be required to run SQL Server in a clustered manner, but as far as I can tell, it is certainly still recommended if you actually want high availability.

[This guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725955.aspx) discusses clustering of MSDTC for SQL Server 2008. The Microsoft documentation on [Installing BizTalk Server 2010 and BAM in a Multi-Computer Environment](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=191321) also explicitly recommends clustering MSDTC, and links to [these instructions](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=189514) on how to do so.